# How can I duplicate the same items in list, change property values and add it to new list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I have a list of items that have an action. Currently, action property is set to null. What I want to do is copy the items in the list, change its action property to delete string and add it to a new list. I want to do it again with add. So the idea is to have list of same items but one with action delete and another with action add.

So have a list with items like this:

```
{
            "someNumber": "123456",
            "projectName": "Foo Bar",
            "action": "delete"
        },
     {
            "someNumber": "454546",
            "projectName": "Foo Bar",
            "action": "delete"
        },
     {
            "someNumber": "123456",
            "projectName": "Foo Bar",
            "action": "add"
        },
     {
            "someNumber": "454546",
            "projectName": "Foo Bar",
            "action": "add"
        }
```

Where I duplicated the 2 items above that initially had action = null but now there's one for delete and add.

I have this code snippet here:

```
List<Leader> leadersToDeleteForUpdating = newLeaders.stream().filter(l-> !"add".equals(l.getAction()) && l.getEndDate() == null).collect(toList());
leadersToDeleteForUpdating.forEach(l->l.setAction("delete"));

List<Leader> leadersToAddForUpdating = newLeaders.stream().filter(l-> !"add".equals(l.getAction()) && l.getEndDate() == null).collect(toList());
leadersToAddForUpdating.forEach(l->l.setAction("add"));

List<Leader> leadersToDeleteAndAddForUpdating = new ArrayList<>(leadersToDeleteForUpdating);
leadersToDeleteAndAddForUpdating.addAll(leadersToAddForUpdating);
```

Right now, it's overriding the item values with action = add and the action = delete items are not copied over. What am I doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting all items with `add` is because you are modifying the same objects all the time. So you have two objects, to the same two objects you first set the action to `delete`, and then you set it to `add`. So by the time you add both lists, both lists are the same, so you end up with 4 items with `add` (if you started with two).

A simple way would be to clone these objects, and call that clone on each of them when you're streaming the lists, like this:

```java
public class Leader {
    private String someNumber;
    private String projectName;
    private String action;

    public Leader(String someNumber, String projectName, String action) {
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public Leader clone() {
        return new Leader(this.getSomeNumber(), this.getProjectName(), this.getAction());
    }
}
```

And then when you're streaming, map and clone them:

```
List<Leader> leadersToDeleteForUpdating = newLeaders.stream().map(l-> l.clone()).filter(l-> !"add".equals(l.getAction())).collect(Collectors.toList());
leadersToDeleteForUpdating.forEach(l->l.setAction("delete"));

List<Leader> leadersToAddForUpdating = newLeaders.stream().map(l-> l.clone()).filter(l-> !"add".equals(l.getAction())).collect(Collectors.toList());
leadersToAddForUpdating.forEach(l->l.setAction("add"));
```

If you want to do this in a more conventional way, you could use the Cloneable interface: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cloneable-interface-in-java/